# Losing Lightning Page's app/record type/profile level assignments/activation after deploying

Tags: lightning

If, like me, you're not making a lightning page an org or app default, you've probably got a *LOT* of boxes to check, in order to make sure every combination of App, Record Type and Profile gets the access they need. Especially because there is no 'check all' option, or way to indicate that record types are the only thing I care about.

I created my lightning page, activated it and assigned it, all in Sandbox. When I pushed it to Production, all those assignments disappeared. I did include all profiles in my changeset.

Is there a way to preserve those assignments in deployments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lightning app metadata (`src/applications/YourAppName.app`) contains the overrides for the app as a whole and also the per recordtype & profile assignments.

```
<CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>View</actionName>
        <comment>Action override created by Lightning App Builder during activation.</comment>
        <content>My_Page</content>
        <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
        <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
        <type>Flexipage</type>
        <pageOrSobjectType>My_Object__c</pageOrSobjectType>
    </actionOverrides>
    <brand>
        <headerColor>#106550</headerColor>
        <logo>myLogo</logo>
        <logoVersion>1</logoVersion>
        <shouldOverrideOrgTheme>false</shouldOverrideOrgTheme>
    </brand>
    <formFactors>Large</formFactors>
    <isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>false</isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>
    <isNavPersonalizationDisabled>true</isNavPersonalizationDisabled>
    <label>My Awesome Application</label>
    <navType>Standard</navType>
    <profileActionOverrides>
        <actionName>View</actionName>
        <content>MyFlexipageName</content>
        <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
        <pageOrSobjectType>My_RecordTypedObject__c</pageOrSobjectType>
        <recordType>My_RecordTypedObject__c.RecordType1</recordType>
        <type>Flexipage</type>
        <profile>Admin</profile>
    </profileActionOverrides>
    <profileActionOverrides>
        <actionName>View</actionName>
        <content>MyFlexipageName</content>
        <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
        <pageOrSobjectType>My_RecordTypedObject__c</pageOrSobjectType>
        <recordType>My_RecordTypedObject__c.RecordType1</recordType>
        <type>Flexipage</type>
        <profile>Standard</profile>
    </profileActionOverrides>
```

The object level flexipage override is similarly contained in the `objectName.object` metadata for each object.

```
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <!-- snip -->
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>Tab</actionName>
        <type>Default</type>
    </actionOverrides>
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>View</actionName>
        <comment>Action override updated by Lightning App Builder during activation.</comment>
        <content>My_Page</content>
        <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
        <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
        <type>Flexipage</type>
    </actionOverrides>
    <allowInChatterGroups>false</allowInChatterGroups>
```

The profile settings themselves do not contain this flexipage assignment metadata. The profile settings does include the home tab override per profile.

```
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <profileActionOverrides>
        <actionName>Tab</actionName>
        <content>MyFlexipage_For_Home_Tab</content>
        <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
        <pageOrSobjectType>standard-home</pageOrSobjectType>
        <type>Flexipage</type>
    </profileActionOverrides>
```

This can all be retrieved and deployed via the metadata API, so it should work the same in Change Sets.

**Update**: Looking at the [documentation for the ProfileActionOverrides](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profileactionoverride.htm), it looks like other profile based overrides can be selected when creating the Change Set that aren't available in a packaging scenario.

> ProfileActionOverrides aren’t supported in packaging. They are supported in change sets, but you have to add them manually.

Can you confirm which elements you included as part of the change set?

Comment: Mark, I included the Lightning page itself, all org profiles, and the record type that the page assignments involved. Did not include Lightning Apps, which I guess are part of the trio that make up the combinations to assign. 

From what you've written, I take it I'd need to include the Apps in the changeset as well, in order to capture those per-profile/recordtype assignments?

Comment: I don't have an org with a sandbox handy to test it out myself but I would say yes, you should include the App in the change set too.

Comment: Alright I'll give it a try. Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 0):

Tested in changeset: you have to add: Lightning Page(if give an error, add all lightning record page related to that app )
App
Record Type (maybe not , but i used lightning record pages related to app ,recordtype and profile)
Profiles(maybe not)
with all these components, the "view page assigment" in lightning record page is loaded correctly .