# Where default flexi page assignment for a custom object is stored?

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, metadata

I need to automate assignment of default flexi page for both Desktop or Mobile experience. However, I am not sure how can I do that.

Where default flexi page assignment for a custom object is stored in metadata?

Comment: fyi, there's plenty of questions relating to this: [1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324560/deploy-flexipage-assignment), [2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324289/how-do-i-deploy-an-org-level-lightning-record-page-flexipage-assignment-throug?rq=1), [3](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/353777/how-to-deploy-assignement-of-compact-layout-record-lightning-page-to-record-ty/353819#353819), [4](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/234844/losing-lightning-pages-app-record-type-profile-level-assignments-activation-aft)

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi, no, the question is not about application settings

Answer (score 0):

If you retrieve an Object, for example, `Contract`, you may find the following sections

```
<actionOverrides>
    <actionName>View</actionName>
    <comment>Action override created by Lightning App Builder during activation.</comment>
    <content>Contract_Record_Page</content>
    <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
    <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
    <type>Flexipage</type>
</actionOverrides>
<actionOverrides>
    <actionName>View</actionName>
    <comment>Action override created by Lightning App Builder during activation.</comment>
    <content>Contract_Record_Page</content>
    <formFactor>Small</formFactor>
    <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
    <type>Flexipage</type>
</actionOverrides>
<actionOverrides>
    <actionName>View</actionName>
    <type>Default</type>
</actionOverrides>
```

which determine the FlexiPage assignments.